# Determine if someone uses Nginx, Apache or Lighttpd

Tags: php, apache, nginx, webserver, lighttpd

I am trying to determine if someone is running Nginx, Apache, Lighttpd or another webserver in PHP.

I tried this with the predefined $_SERVER variable, but I am not sure if and how this will work since I have only been able to test this on Apache 2.4.
Does anyone have an idea on how I can determine what webserver someone is using?

Comment: What problem will knowing what webserver they use solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the webserver is  not configured to hide server name, then you can determine server name by

```
<?php
   echo $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'];
?>
```

1) Apache cannot be directly configured to hide server name, But it can be achieved by installing `mod-security`

2)nginx and lighttpd can be easily configured to hide server fingerprinting.

Comment: That assumes that the server is (a) Not suppressing it entirely and (b) Telling the truth. The question seems to be asking about the server the code is running on rather than arbitrary third party servers anyway.

Comment: The comments don't make sense because the answer has been completely re-written from the original.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'];
```